# How do I delete a book from iBooks on Mac Book Pro

Tags: high-sierra

How do I delete a book from iBooks on MBP OSX.

Comment: You control-click on the book, then click delete. Is that not working for you?

Comment: In the Books app on your Mac, click Library in the toolbar.

    In your library, select the book you want to delete, then press the Delete key.

Comment: @Buscar Your comment is a copy-paste from the URL I linked to but without attribution. Perhaps if you have the same answer as an existing answer you should upvote it?

Comment: @grg I am sorry, I did not pay attention. Feel free to delete it. Now looking at your one line answer, I do believe you should leave such simple answers to newcomers to earn some points.

Comment: @Buscar An interesting point you might want to raise on meta. I encourage you to have a read through this related meta discussion first: [Force top level point holders to wait](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137626/222623)

Comment: @grg thank you for the link, while the discussion there ended in 2012 you can see my contribution to the topic. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320851/217966

Answer (score 1):

> In your library, select the book you want to delete, then press the Delete key.

https://support.apple.com/guide/books/delete-books-from-your-mac-ibks67184a3a/mac